# In the most recent version of Microsoft Word, is it possible to disable auto-capitalization for a custom style?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make a style that displays computer code. Code is case sensitive, so when I type I want it to not be automatically capitalized. I have created a custom style and I disabled automatic spell checking in it, but that didn't do the trick. I know that I can copy from an actual code editor and I do that, but I want to streamline my workflow by removing the extra step.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Z immediately after the capitalization.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can live with that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by executing next steps:

1. Go to “File” tab.
2. Options
3. Proofing
4. Click “AutoCorrect Options.”
5. Click the box that says “Capitalize First Letter of Sentences” in the AutoCorrect tab to clear it and remove the default setting.

P.S. In MacOS version is `Tools / AutoCorrect Options`

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to apply it for every style. I just want it removed for my one custom style. Is that possible?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky, yes, this apply to entire Word. I am not aware of other way to disable this option (or make it in style)

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks!

Comment: this File / Options isn't available in the Word for Mac 365 version.  It's Tools / AutoCorrect Options

Comment: @Vorsprung, good information, thank you